# How do I iterate through a text file to print into another text file?

Tags: java, while-loop, iteration, text-files

I created three text files, inputt.txt, outputt.txt, & errorr.txt. Inputt.txt is for input, outputt.txt is supposed to print all numbers from inputt.txt that are valid integers, and errorr.txt prints all the errors from the input text file. I am having trouble with iteration. The System.out.println prints all the numbers from inputt.txt just fine; however, when i try to print all the numbers into outputt.txt, it only prints the first line of numbers. Here is my code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Lab5_Exceptions_Redo extends Exception {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        String file = "inputt.txt";
        String file1 = "outputt.txt";
        String file2 = "errorr.txt";

        PrintWriter errorr = new PrintWriter(file2);
        PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(file2);

        PrintWriter outputt = new PrintWriter(file1);
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File(file));
        while (scan.hasNext()) {
            try {

                String number = scan.nextLine();
                int num = Integer.parseInt(number);
                System.out.println(num);
                outputt.println(num);
            } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                errorr.println("There was an input mismatch error.");
                errorr.println(e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace(ps);
            } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
                errorr.println("There is no such element.");
                errorr.println(e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace(ps);
            } catch (UnsupportedOperationException e) {
                errorr.println("An unsupported operation occured.");
                errorr.println(e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace(ps);
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                errorr.println("Number Format Exception.");
                errorr.println(e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace(ps);
            }

            errorr.close();
            outputt.close();
        }
        scan.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: You are closing `outputt` in the loop. Move it outside to fix. Voting to close as a typo.

Comment: I can't close it outside because inside is where I declare variables, and I cannot move the variable outside because they must be in my try statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PrintWriter stream variable errorr should move outside the for loop.  Try the following version of code.

```
public class Lab5_Exceptions_Redo extends Exception {

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

    String file = "inputt.txt";
    String file1 = "outputt.txt";
    String file2 = "errorr.txt";

    PrintWriter errorr = new PrintWriter(file2);
    PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(file2);

    PrintWriter outputt = new PrintWriter(file1);
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File(file));
    while (scan.hasNext()) {
        try {
            String number = scan.nextLine();
            int num = Integer.parseInt(number);
            System.out.println(num);
            outputt.println(num);
        } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            errorr.println("There was an input mismatch error.");
            errorr.println(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace(ps);
        } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
            errorr.println("There is no such element.");
            errorr.println(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace(ps);
        } catch (UnsupportedOperationException e) {
            errorr.println("An unsupported operation occured.");
            errorr.println(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace(ps);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            errorr.println("Number Format Exception.");
            errorr.println(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace(ps);
        }
    }
    errorr.close();
    outputt.close();
    scan.close();
}
}
```